# I have a picker that is in a collectionview but I'm unsure how to get the value

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uicollectionview, picker

I have a collectionview which has a [Label(day of the week] - [checkbox] - [picker with times].

I want the user to be able to select a day and time, after that I want to then pass those values to my database. So far I am able to select the day and pass this value on. However I am struggling to refence the value in the picker. I think this is due to it being a list in my object. I have tried booking.Listtimes but that is just a list. I want the value selected.

My ViewModel:

```
public class RepeatMonthly
    {
        public string Day { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public List<WalkTimes> _ListTimes { get; set; }
    }
    private WalkTimes _selectedTimes;
    public WalkTimes SelectedTimes
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedTimes;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedTimes, value);
        }
    }

public ObservableCollection<RepeatMonthly> DayList { get; set; }

public CreateWeeklyScheduleViewModel()
    {
        ListTimes = WalkTimesService.GetTimes().OrderBy(c => c.Key).ToList();

        DayList = new ObservableCollection<RepeatMonthly>()
    {
        new RepeatMonthly(){Day="Every Monday", Selected = false, _ListTimes = ListTimes},
        new RepeatMonthly(){Day="Every Tuesday", Selected = false, _ListTimes = ListTimes},
        new RepeatMonthly(){Day="Every WednesDay", Selected = false, _ListTimes = ListTimes},
        new RepeatMonthly(){Day="Every Thursday", Selected = false, _ListTimes = ListTimes},
        new RepeatMonthly(){Day="Every Friday", Selected = false, _ListTimes = ListTimes},
        new RepeatMonthly(){Day="Every Saturday", Selected = false, _ListTimes = ListTimes},
        new RepeatMonthly(){Day="Every Sunday", Selected = false, _ListTimes = ListTimes}
    };

        source = new ObservableCollection<PetProfile>();                     
    }
```

My Xaml:

```
<CollectionView  x:Name="RepeatCollectionView" HorizontalOptions="Center"  ItemsSource="{Binding DayList}" HeightRequest="350">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="0" RowDefinitions="25, 20" ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Day}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium"
                               Margin="5,0"
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="SelectDayCheckBox" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalOptions="End" IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" BindingContext="{Binding .}" CheckedChanged="SelectDayCheckBox_CheckedChanged"/>
                        <Picker x:Name="SelectTimeOfWalkPicker" Title="--Select Walk Start Time--" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding _ListTimes}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTimes}" />
                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

my .cs page:

```
private async void SubmitBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        foreach (RepeatMonthly booking in (BindingContext as CreateWeeklyScheduleViewModel).DayList)
        {
            if (booking.Selected)
            {
                await passtoDataBase(booking.Day, "where time variable goes");
            }
        }
        
        await DisplayAlert("Success", "Booked Successfully", "OK");
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MyBookingsPage)}");
    }
```

properties of WalkTimes object:

```
public class WalkTimes
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: which are the properties of `WalkTimes`  object ?

Comment: I've edited to show the properties

Comment: You're binding the SelectedItem to SelectedTimes on the VM, but the SelectedTimes property needs to be on the RepeatMonthly class to work like you're expecting. When you're inside a collection view, your binding context becomes the item being displayed by the collection view

Comment: Ah I see how it works now. Well I tried putting that code in RepeatMonthly but I am getting an error. An object refeernce is requied for the non static field. Could you help show how the code would look. Thanks

Comment: ... also post the error message you get. StackOverflow works best when you provide all the info you can. This makes it easier to help you, and also is useful to future people if they have a similar problem. Thanks.